# I want to creat a table but it gives me error 1046

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `info` (
  `roll_no` integer(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NULL,
  `fname` varchar(45) NULL,
  `reg_no` varchar(45) NULL,
  `cnic` varchar(45) NULL,
  `sesion` varchar(45) NULL,
  `prog` varchar(50) NULL,
  `cent` varchar(50) NULL,
  `inst` varchar(50) NULL,
  `exam` varchar(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roll_no`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 13
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove that extra comma after PRIMARY KEY. Use this SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `info` (
  `roll_no` integer(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NULL,
  `fname` varchar(45) NULL,
  `reg_no` varchar(45) NULL,
  `cnic` varchar(45) NULL,
  `sesion` varchar(45) NULL,
  `prog` varchar(50) NULL,
  `cent` varchar(50) NULL,
  `inst` varchar(50) NULL,
  `exam` varchar(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roll_no`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma at the end of

```
PRIMARY KEY (`roll_no`),
                       ^ right there
```

Answer (score 1):

Check by removing comma `,` after

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`roll_no`),
```

And then if error is exist, then it is the old version..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is that extra comma after `PRIMARY KEY ( roll_no )`